# How Can i pass my validations and OnChangeText function to the react native masked input

Tags: react-native

I have two different input fields.One is normal react masked input and another is maked input from

import { TextInputMask } from "react-native-masked-text";

I have a function named as onChange Which is assign to normal input which is changing and validating the values that user enter to the input filesd.

```
              <Input
                onChangeText={onChange}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                keyboardType={keyboardType}
                secureTextEntry={password}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                multiline={multiline}
              />
```

Now i want to add the this onChange function to the masked input. So that i can validate and change the value of the masked input as normal input filed.
So i write a code like this to do so.

```
            <MaskTextInput
               type={"custom"}
               options={{
                 mask: "(999) 999-9999"
               }}
               onChangeText={text => {
                 onChange(text)
               }}
               underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
               keyboardType={keyboardType}
               secureTextEntry={password}
               placeholder={placeholder}
             />
```

But it didn,t validate or chnage the value of the masked input as the user type in this input feild.

How can i do this.

Comment: Can you please share "onChange" function?

Answer (score 0):

Please add below constructor code
`constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      sampleText: ''
    }
}`
and add below code in render
`<TextInputMask
   type={"custom"}
   options={{
             mask: "(999) 999-9999"
   }}
   onChangeText={sampleText => this.setState({ sampleText })}
   value={this.state.sampleText} />`
Or you can cusomize your "onChange" function accordingly by adding `this.setState({ sampleText })`in it.